# MSMQ on a domain controller defaults to workgroup mode, how to switch to Domain mode?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dns, msmq, domaincontroller, workgroup

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine acting as Domain Controller for a test domain and I have installed MSMQ on this server including the "Message Queue Server", "Directory Services Integration" and "Message Queueing Triggers" features.   I've also installed MSMQ onto a second machine in the domain that is running Server 2003.

The install on the domain controller apears to default to workgroup mode, theres no Public Queues options and attempting to programatically create one results in a message "A workgroup installation computer does not support this operation".  The install on thw 2k3 server defaults to Domain mode complete with Public Queues support.

Can anyone give me instructions on how to get MSMQ working in Domain mode on the Domain Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I got the permissions in the AD a little wrong when installing MSMQ.  Removing MSMQ setting the right permissions and reinstalling the queue fixed the problem.

Comment: I was working on a legacy system and could not reinstall MSMQ after uninstalling it (`Unable to Load MQQM.dll`).  The solution is given in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322156.  I am not sure for how long this might still be relevant to anyone, but I decided to post the solution for posterity.